# Can apps detect it is a Virtual PC?

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

Some games let you earn coins by installing some trial software.  I don't want to install on my main PC but install just on a Virtual PC .  But sometimes some trial software installation didn't give the coins.  Besides the possibility that the trail didn't honor their promise, could it be that they detect it is a Virtual PC and not give it?  Can you make a Virtual PC not identifiable as a VPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to detect virtual machines.
Check out: [Detect if your program is running inside a Virtual Machine.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/VmDetect.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to detect a virtual machine - it doesn't matter if you run Virtual PC or VMware. However, I don't think it is the issue in this particular case, since many people use softwares in a virtual machine. I think it's normal, not an anomaly to detect.